# hibernate 5 maven and mysql No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/projeto

Tags: mysql, hibernate, maven

i'm getting this error: "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/project", i'm using eclipse, maven, hibernate 5, and i've already instaled the mysql connector, but still not working, any ideis?

the prompt error.

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet] in 
context with path [/projeto] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested 
exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root 
causejava.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/projeto
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverManagerConnectionCreator.java:34)
```

the hiberate and mysql dependencies in my pom file.

```
<hibernate-core.version>5.0.1.Final</hibernate-core.version>
    <hibernate-commons-annotations.version>5.0.1.Final</hibernate-commons-annotations.version>
    <mysql-connector-java.version>6.0.6</mysql-connector-java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-commons-annotations.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

[jars on maven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmmnr.png)

and the code where the error came from. *the code stops in the comented line.

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
static {
    StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .build();
//Metadata metaData = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();

    sessionFactory = metaData.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

    return sessionFactory;

    }
}
```

Comment: what is your mysql server version?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for my problem, but first of all, thanks to Zeromus for answering me. The problem, in my case, is occurring when I'm trying to instantiate this object:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
static {
    StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
```

The method `.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();` was not finding the hibernate xml file. I just refreshed the project and the problem was solved, I hope it can help someone. It was so simple, but took a long time to find it.